# How to disable ssh connection for group?

Tags: ssh

How to disable ssh connection for group? OS: debian, I tryed to change ssh_config file, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question here on serverfault for more information](https://serverfault.com/questions/285800/how-to-disable-ssh-login-with-password-for-some-users), try to use the `Match` syntax in `sshd_config` to exclude a certain group from logging in.

`Match Group groupname
    PasswordAuthentication no`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. http://pastebin.com/rBBfwddR
I tryed to restart ssh and vps.

Comment: I think the problem is here that you're editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which is the ssh client configuration instead of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which is the ssh server configuration.

Comment: Ye, I'm dumb, thx for help ;)